# Error using \ Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options

Tags: out-of-memory, matlab, matlab-figure

I need to load two data files each of which have 6 columns and I want to plot the ratio of a column from first data file and another column from the second data file. But I keep getting a memory error. None of the numbers are zeros. I plotted the same in Excel. Worked ok. But I need it in Matlab, What do I do?

My current code is something like this:

```
    load file1.dat;
    y=file1(:,2);
    time=file1(:,1);
    hold on;

    load file2.dat;
    x=file2(:,5);

    figure;
    plot (t,y/(3*x),'LineWidth',1);
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Mitochondrial Calcium (um)');
```

This is the error I get:

> Error using  \
>   Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
>   options.
>
> Error in plotCmyo (line 9) --> File name, line 9 is the one with the plot command
>   plot(t,y/x, 'LineWidth',1);

Comment: What happens here, is that the forward-slash operator `/` acts differently based on the structure of its operands. If both are vectors or matrices it will attempt to find a linear solution to the given system of linear equations: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html. In your case, it will be a highly overdetermined system of many equations sharing a single unknown variable. This might be the cause of hitting the memory limit of MATLAB. Below, Kleist changes the operator to the element-wise division operator - which is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `y./(3*x)` to do element-wise division.

Note the operator: `./`

Comment: Thank so much. I am such a newbie to Matlab, I don't know so much. Your answer is perfect, just what I needed. Thanks again.